# What is the best way to calling a code behind function from JavaScript?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, architecture

My project in vs2012 webform C#.it’s an ERP  project. For better performance I want to use javascript with server side code.

Recently,after a lot of google search on this topic I found the different ways for calling a code behind function from JavaScript. There are different ways to call a code behind function and list down here .
According to me, there are four main possible ways to call a function from JavaScript:

1. Pagemethods in JS AND WebMethod in code behind class
2. IPostBackEventHandler in codebehind class AND _doPostBack in JS
3. ICallbackEventHandler in code behind class
4. Ajax/Jquery AND ASHX handler

Here, each way has its own advantage and disadvantage. I need to calling server side functions more frequently, then which one is better for me? It will be great help for me if you specify advantage of your valuable suggestion.
If you check attached picture then you can realized how frequently I need to use server side function.
Any type of suggestion will be acceptable.

[image]
NOTE: In my UI there are lot of tab in one page and each contain more than one grid,dropdownlist and textbox.**behind** is the C# code server side event functionality and **frontend** is the client side  functionality,if have any other confusion please inform me.

Comment: Not the best way, but he easiest way, put a button on the aspx the codebehind is tied to.  Hide the button with display none.  Call __doPostBack and pass in the buttons client id.  Then use the server side click event of the button to process the postback.

Comment: @shamim, your question is not at all clear. What do you mean by "behind"?

Comment: CodeBehind is clear, aspx files can have a compiled class tied to them (The concept is called a CodeBehind).  To the op's question the best way is to implement IPostBackEventHandler and use __doPostBack to invoke the control that implements it.

Comment: Roamer-1888 tanks for comment. behind is the C# code server side event functionality and frontend is the client side  functionality,if have any other confusion please inform me.

Comment: Also, best really depends on what you want to do.  If your trying to invoke an event driven component in the same flow as your user conttrol, web control, Page, or other kind of control, then yes IPostBackEventHandler is best.

However if you just want to process some JSONData or something then  using an ASHXHandler is a good way to do it.  In the code behind for the ASHXHandler just set the content type to application&lt;json then write the json string to the Response with Response.Write.

Comment: If it were me, with a form that complex, I would design an HttpHandler to return me a JSON object for the ENTIRE form.  Then I would use Angular JS for the front end form to template it out and it's $http object to get the Json data from the ASHX controller.

Comment: Ryios thanks for your valuable information,it will be helpful for me if you provide me any example......